# The run destination iPad Retina is not valid for Running the scheme 'gov_inspector'

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator, xcode7.3

I am getting the following error dialogue when running an app.

**The run destination iPad Retina is not valid for Running the scheme 'gov_inspector'.**

iPad Retina’s iOS Simulator 9.1 doesn’t match CBSA Field Inspect.app’s iOS Simulator 9.3 deployment target. Upgrade iPad Retina’s iOS Simulator version or lower CBSA Field Inspect.app’s deployment target.